# About the proof of Zeta Transform

Tags: transformation, z-transform

I have to prove
$$Z[k^n]=(-1)^nD^n\left(\frac{z}{z-1}\right)$$ where $$D=z\frac{d}{dz}$$ and $n$ varies over the set $\mathbb{Z}$
My book doesn't give me any advice; how can I go further?

Comment: Do you mean $n$, not $k$?

Comment: Sorry I edited, i meant $n$

Answer (score 1):

Define:

$$f_n(z)=Z[k^n]=\sum_{k=0}^\infty k^n z^{-k}$$

Prove it by induction on $n$.

If $n=0$, then $$f_0(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^{-k} = \frac{1}{1-z^{-1}}=\frac{z}{z-1} = (-1)^0D^0\left(\frac{z}{z-1}\right)$$

Next, show that:

$$f_{n+1}(z)=(-1)D[f_n(z)]$$

by:

$$\begin{align}(-1)D[f_n(z)]&=(-1)D\left[\sum_{k=0}^\infty k^n z^{-k}\right] 
\\&= (-1)z\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)k^{n+1} z^{-k-1}\\&=f_{n+1}(z)
\end{align}$$

More generally:

$$Z[ka_k] = (-1)D\left(Z[a_k]\right)$$

This is the [property called differentiation on the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform#Properties) for the Z-transform.